# Insertar atributos en todos los campos en un ModelForm Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-forms

Estoy con un problema de un `modelForm` en Django 1.8, el código es el siguiente:

```
class TrabajoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trabajo
        exclude = ['fecha_solicitud', 'revisado']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Lo que deseo es darle una clase css a todos los campos del formulario, según el error que me da Django al momento de usarlo es el `self` no se encuentra definido, ¿Qué puedo hacer?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar la propia clase y a `self` al invocar el método `super()`. Algo así:

```
class TrabajoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trabajo
        exclude = ['fecha_solicitud', 'revisado']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrabajoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

También debes referirte a `self.fields` cada vez que lo llamas, aunque sea dentro del ciclo `for`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda!!!!